# Disable a link for couple of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a book-website with a jQuery-plugin. Every time a link is clicked, the book-page switches to the next page and the .active class switches from link. The problem is that if you click fast between the pages, the active class switches but the movement of the book is too slow so you don't hop to the next page.

I'm trying disable the link after u clicked on one. My idea was just removing an attribute for a couple of seconds like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(e){

    .. switch page using id
    .. switch .active

    $(".button li a").removeAttr("id");
}
```

So when the page is loaded, and the active class is switched. U cannot click on another link until the attribute is put back on.

How can remove an attribute for a couple of seconds? Or are there other options to disable a link for a period of time without removing the attribute?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) for when the animation finishes.

Comment: what is the plugin you're using? does it have an event that fires when the page finished loading?

Comment: I'm using booklet plugin

Comment: Yeah, better to do a callback on the animation than guess at a timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy (but a bit hacky) way to accomplish this is returning early out of the handler if the action is already in progress:

```
var pageIsTurning = false;
$('.button').click(function(e){
    if (pageIsTurning) { return; }

    // do your stuff and change the page

}):
```

According to the [docs](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/documentation) of the booklet plugin you can bind to the `bookletstart` and `bookletchange` events which are where you'd update the `pageIsTurning` variable.

```
$(".selector").bind("bookletstart", function(event, data) {
    pageIsTurning = true;
});

$(".selector").bind("bookletchange", function(event, data) {
    pageIsTurning = false;
});
```

Note that this approach wouldn't work if you have more than one booklet on the page but could easily be adapted.

Comment: @user3231419 - I noticed you haven't accepted answers to your questions. If an answer helps you, mark it as the accepted answer using the little tick to the left. Glad you got it sorted. :)